# Proof that the inverse exists in the group of units of the additive group of modulo n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Here is a statement I am trying to prove, that will allow me to prove the inverse exists in the group of units of the additive group of modulo n.

> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. If gcd$(a,n) = 1$, there
>   exists $0\leq b < n$ such that $ab \equiv 1$ (mod $n$), and gcd$(b,n)
>  = 1$.

The proof I can think of is this:

> Since $(a,n) = 1$, there exists some $c_1$ and $c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$
>   such that $c_1a+c_2n = 1$. Then $c_1a = -c_2n + 1$, and this means
>   $c_1a \equiv 1$ (mod $n$). Consider the ideal $J$ generated by $c_1$ and
>   $n$, which is J := $\{x_1c_1 + x_2n : x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, then $1 \in J$, and  since $1$ is the smallest
>   positive integer, it must be the generator for $J$ and hence it is the
>   greatest common divisor for $c_1$ and $n$.

**But this proof does not consider the inequality. So my question is: from where does the inequality arise?**

Comment: Which inequality are you talking about?

Comment: $0≤b<n$ that appears in the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the problem. You already proved that there exists $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$ab\equiv 1$(mod $n$) and $gcd(b,n)=1$. If your question is why $0\leq b<n$ then it just follows from the fact that you can always take $0\leq c<n$ such that $c\equiv b$(mod $n$) and then $ac\equiv ab$(mod $n$). So without loss of generality you can say $b$ itself is in $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. My question is about why should $b$ obeys $0≤b<n$, but I think your answer has completely solved the problem. It seems I just overlook the fact that 'you can always take 0≤c<n such that c≡b(mod n) and then ac≡ab(mod n).'

Comment: Yes. The specific $b$ you found might not satisfy $0\leq b<n$, but multiplication mod $n$ doesn't depend on which number you choose to represent the equivalence class, so you can always take one from $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ which is congruent to $b$.